# xero-api Initialise Problems

Tags: xero-api

I have attempted to set up xero-node passing in the consumer key and consumer secret along with the app name as the user Agent.  However when I do a test call e.g. xeroClient.core.users.getUsers() the code just seems to freeze not giving any errors however I cannot move any further.

Comment: You can see a gist here: https://gist.github.com/BrianSHenderson/c27f719803afc7f21583c27670716e8f

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to post a gist of the code you are using?

What App type are you using (Private, Public or Partner)?

Have you seen the code samples on the main GitHub page? There is also a sample app here: https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node-sample-app

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, its a Private App Type (I didn't see an example Private type in the same app).

Comment: const xero = require('xero-node');
    const config = {
      userAgent : "NMM",
      consumerKey: "XXXX",
      consumerSecret: "XXXX",
      privateKeyPath: `${process.env.PWD}/public/xeroprivatekey.pem`,
    };

Comment: const xeroClient = new xero.PrivateApplication(config);

Comment: xeroClient.core.users.getUsers()
    .then(contacts => {
      console.log('**')
        contacts.forEach(contact => {
            console.log(contact.Name);
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

Comment: Hi. I imagine it might be an issue with the private key.

See here for an issue: https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node/issues/116

There is an example here: https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node#app-usage

Can you copy and paste that one and give it ago?